# GPUImage /usr/local/bin/appledoc: No such file or directory

Tags: swift, gpuimage

Spent a while trying to build some of the swift examples for GPUImage and kept running into this error. I added Appledoc using Homebrew and continued to see this error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 16):

According to this https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/214 with the great Brad Larson where he explained that I had to be trying to build and run the Documentation rather than the actual project.

In other words I needed to turn this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

Now I'm no longer trying to run the documentation and things work great. Enjoy!